# How HTTP requests are Automatically being redirected to HTTPS?

Tags: wordpress, http, redirect, https, dns

I am using Cloudflare SSL on my WordPress site, but I don't know that how HTTP request are automatically redirecting to HTTPS.    I have not set any redirects.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that your CloudFlare site uses HSTS. See this blog post for details:

https://blog.cloudflare.com/enforce-web-policy-with-hypertext-strict-transport-security-hsts/

Comment: Hii, RomanK HSTS is disabled in my site's option. Only TLS is enabled here

Comment: Do you have a traffic capture where your site automatically switches to HTTPS?

Comment: No I dont have a traffic capture